# Sass variables not working in keyframe mixin

Tags: css, sass, css-animations

I currently have a simple keyframes mixin that looks like this:

```
@mixin keys($animationName) {
  @-webkit-keyframes $animationName {
    @content;
  }
  @-moz-keyframes $animationName {
    @content;
  }  
  @-ms-keyframes $animationName {
    @content;
  }
  @-o-keyframes $animationName {
    @content;
  }  
  @keyframes $animationName {
    @content;
  }
}
```

Which I am using for simple fade in animations like this

```
@include keys(fadeIn) {
 0% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

For some reason, the variable is not translating properly in the css. The css file looks like this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes $animationName {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes $animationName {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes $animationName {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes $animationName {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes $animationName {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

I feel like this is something super simple I am missing but I can't seem to figure it out. All my other variables work except this one. What do you think would be causing this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it by adding #{animationName} to everything.

```
@mixin keys($animationName) {
  @-webkit-keyframes #{$animationName} {
    @content;
  }
  @-moz-keyframes #{$animationName} {
    @content;
  }  
  @-ms-keyframes #{$animationName} {
    @content;
  }
  @-o-keyframes #{$animationName} {
    @content;
  }  
  @keyframes #{$animationName} {
    @content;
  }
}
```